# Android project(4.4.2) is not running after eclipse & adt update

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I updated my Sdk manager,eclipse & ADT but now old projects are not
running. Its giving like error below

> C:\Users\Deepak\Desktop\New
> folder\VishwasBawa\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error
> retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
> name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
>
> C:\Users\Deepak\Desktop\New
> folder\VishwasBawa\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error
> retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
> name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: fix library dependencies

Comment: i did that but giving like error R.cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Add appcompact-v7 library & clean your project.

Comment: But the thing is android project build target is android 4.4.2

Comment: No giving errors like R cannot be resolved after did this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `appcompat` v7 library in your project. If you do, to resolve the error you've got, open `project.properties` file in your imported `appcompat` v7 project and change the target value to `target.target=android-21` and save the file. Then, clean all Android projects. This should fix the errors in your Android project.

*Note: Changing the target value to `target.target=android-21` is equivalent to selecting the **Properties** of the `appcompat` project. Then, select **Android | Project Build Target | Android 5.0.1**.*

Comment: You probably need to change the directive to `android:targetSdkVersion="21"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` of your main project.